# How does pandas.DataFrame.replace works?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I need to remove '$' symbol in 'price' column. I used pd.DataFrame.replace to do that.

[replace result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiYAi.png)

Why did nothing happen?

If I use str.replace it works: [str.replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3mw5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
listings['price'].str.replace({'$':''},regex=True,inplace=True)
```